# Patching to a specific date

Tags: apt, updates, patch

I am very new to Linux and I am struggling with a request to patch multiple environments at work. We need all the servers to be patched to a specific date so I am trying to figure out a way to write an apt-get update/upgrade command that will only update to a specific date.
For example:
Env1 - gets patched on 4/4
Env2 - gets patched on 4/10 but want the same patches that are in Env1
Prod - gets patched on 4/15 but want the same patches that are in Env1

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need a centralized management environment where you can issue update commands via that management platform rather than just a 'script.

Comment: We actually have Bigfix but we are having issues in that these Linux instances are in AWS and are running Ubuntu with an "optimized" AWS kernel, so the last month we tried to patch it blew up all the instances and they had to be restored... I am planning on opening a case with Bigfix but have a feeling they are going to tell us it's an AWS issue so I just wanted to see what other options there were.

Answer (score 0):

A few building blocks for accomplishing this:

You could set up a private repository (or multiple ones) with reprepro, discipline how this repository is updated, and use it as the sole apt-source for your servers.

apt takes packagename=version arguments, and will install the exact version requested. So called "pinning" is another way to enforce this.

Once you can specify exact versions, there are multiple ways of ensuring your end goal - eg by parsing the versions installed on a "master" system on a given date from dpkg -l (do not get confused by the versions being truncated in plain terminal output, they won't be if piped or redirected to a file).

Also, make sure you do not start from a position where anything on the target system is NEWER than what you want - this tends to invite all sorts of friction with dependencies and postinst/preinst scripts.

Do not get discouraged by the "Most current versions or you're a loser" crowd - these people tend to be competent enough to know why most current versions have security benefits, but do not yet understand things like QA processes or risk management.

Comment: Thanks, I think we may look at hosting our own repository...